Though vs However / Negation vs Partial Negation
Here are three examples of using 'though' as a negation (Can it be used any other way?).
Of the three examples, which ones are correct?
1- Everything I told them was correct, 'though' I forgot a few things.
2- 'Though' I forgot a few things, everything I told them was correct.
3- Everything I told them was correct. I forgot a few things, 'though'.
My feeling is that Examples 2 & 3 represent most common usage. For some reason, Example 1 feels awkward to me.

Also, would someone be willing to explain the subtle difference in nuance between 'however' and 'though'? Is there a difference?
I read somewhere that 'though' communicates partial negation, and that 'however' communicates negation.
I am a bit confused about this. I would definitely appreciate some clarity with regards to this.

1-3 are all fine with though. If you replaced it with however, 2 would not work and 1 would have to be two sentences. "However, I forgot a few things."

The clause headed by though concedes something that qualifies the assertion in the matrix clause.  "negates" overstates things.  "Though the train is often delayed outside the terminal, it always leaves this station on time." however does a similar thing but the clause it heads  follows after:  "The train always leaves this station on time; however, it is often delayed outside the terminal."  The clause headed by though can precede or follow the matrix clause.

Because of the semantics of everything, it makes no sense to place parenthetical adverbial I forgot a few things immediately after Everything I told them. But if instead of everything we used what, it would be perfectly possible to say What I told them, though I forgot a few things, was correct.

All three of your sentences are fine.
It’s not unreasonable to describe the difference between though and however in terms of strength. A though B suggests that one would typically find B’s being true less of a surprise (given that  A is true) than does A however B. In that sense, however is more like but.

Paul Tanenbaum: Could you give me an example or some examples to illustrate your point? I would appreciate it.

One might say, “Though I was already tired, I decided to go to the party anyway.”  Being tired is not typically a particularly high bar to attending a party.  One might also say, “You are permitted to examine the document. However, photography is prohibited, you must wear cotton gloves, and our staff will escort you and monitor your activity.” The restrictions on your liberty in handling (both literally and metaphorically) the document are substantial and extend well beyond what might be typical for accessing documents in one’s research.
